# Getting matplotlib chart axes to intersect at the Origin (0,0)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some code to create a chart using matplotlib (version 2.0.0) in Python (version 3.5.5) using a Jupyter notebook and am able to produce a chart but I need the chart axes to intersect at (0,0) or the origin. How do I do that? I have got the code below.

Please let me know how I can get it to intersect at 0,0.

Thanks a lot in advance.

```
   import numpy as np
   import pandas as pd
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   %matplotlib inline

   a = np.array([0])
   #var1adj = np.append(a,var1)
   f, ax = plt.subplots(1)
   xdata = list(range(0,45))
   ydata = list(range(0,45))
   ax.plot(xdata,ydata)
   ax.set_ylim(bottom=0)
   plt.show(f)
```

Comment: add ax.set_xlim(left=0)

Comment: This works too! Thanks @JunheeShin .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly you wanted something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

a = np.array([0])
#var1adj = np.append(a,var1)
f, ax = plt.subplots(1)
xdata = list(range(0,45))
ydata = list(range(0,45))
ax.plot(xdata,ydata)
ax.plot(0,0, 'bo')
ax.set_ylim(bottom=0)
ax.set_xlim(0)
plt.show(f)
```

Comment: Thanks @Duca ! That Worked. Will accept your answer soon!